# Getting SHOUTcast metadata on the Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stream, metadata, shoutcast

I'm creating an application in Objective-C and I need to get the metadata from a SHOUTcast stream. I tried this:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://202.4.100.2:8000/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request addValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"icy-metadata"];
    [request addValue:@"Winamp 5/3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request addValue:@"audio/mpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I would have to get the headers from this request in order to get the information, right? Unfortunately it keeps returning these headers:

> Date = "17 Apr 2010 21:57:14 -0200";
>
> ```
> "Max-Age" = 0;
> ```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What metadata are you referring to? The song title, artist, and album?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer to this question. Simply append a 7.html at the end of the URL and parse the file.

I.E.
 http://38.96.148.138:7534/7.html

Answer (score 1):

Fernando Valente's solution for this problem

http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2012/03/15/shoutcast-metadata-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that shoutcast does not follow HTTP exchange standards and its response headers and body are not separated by two newlines. NSURLConnection/NSURLResponse are unable to parse out the headers; however, `connection:didReceiveResponse:` is still fired, just with an empty NSURLResponse. This becomes clear if we take a look at data coming in `connection:didReceiveData:`. The first chunk received will contain metadata headers.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and sometimes it returns the metadata, sometimes it doesn't. Is there another way to do that? I tried this:

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
 NSString *metadata  = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSRange range = [metadata rangeOfString:@"StreamTitle=" options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSBackwardsSearch)];
 if(range.length > 0){
  NSLog(@"%@", metadata);
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"%@ no range", metadata);
 }
}